# How do you travel to Serendipity in FFXIII-2?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I have beaten the main storyline, and now I'm looking to complete all the paradox endings. In order to do so, I need to activate my paradox scope at Serendipity. But, I can't seem to figure out how to get there. How do I navigate the Historia Crux to get there?

Answer (score 1):

There are two nodes for *Serendipity* on the Historia Crux: one for the main storyline and another for the *Sazh: Heads or Tails?* DLC.

Using *New Bodhum -003 AF-* as the starting point:

#### Expanded Historia Crux

Main storyline:

1. Go right to *Bresha Ruins -005 AF-*
2. Go up to *Yaschas Massif -010 AF-*
3. Go up to *Oerba -200 AF-*
4. Go right to an empty node
5. Go right to *Yaschas Massif -01X AF-*
6. Go down to *Serendipity -Year Unknown-*

*Sazh: Heads or Tails?* DLC:

1. Go left to an empty node
2. Go down to *Serendipity -??? AF-*

#### Compact Historia Crux

Go right seven times. For the *Sazh: Heads or Tails?* DLC, go up from there.

You can also check out [snesmaster1's map](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/619315-final-fantasy-xiii-2/faqs/63802) on GameFAQs.

Just as an aside, though: there is no paradox ending associated with Serendipity. Only the following locations have paradox endings associated with them:

- *Academia -4XX AF-*
- *Academia -500 AF-*
- *Augusta Tower -200 AF-*
- *Bresha Ruins -005 AF-*
- *A Dying World -700 AF-*
- *Oerba -200 AF-*
- *Sunleth Waterscape -300 AF-*
- *The Void Beyond*

Answer (score 1):

[image: Historia crux map]

Serendipity is node 10 on this map.

There are two ways to get there, this is the way most people will access serendipity when you complete the chapter 3 in sequential order (part 1 then part 2) you get there by opening the gate to the very south in node 12 Yaschas Massif AF01X.

From there you are in an alternate Historia crux. Enter the void beyond, there are a few items hidden around here. Then open the gate in the middle of the map to return to the regular Historia Crux and unlock Serendipity in the process.

Now you just enter it like a normal node.

The second way is if you completed chapter 3 out of sequence (part 2 then part 1.) then only difference is that you have to open a gate in node 13 Sunleth Waterscape AF300 but as I didn't do it this way I am not sure which gate it is.

Node 35 is also serendipity but only accessible if you purchase the Sazh: Heads or Tails  DLC.

references:
http://www.gamerguides.com/final-fantasy-xiii-2/walkthrough-130/episode-1/

Comment: Where'd that picture come from?  Without a source, there's no way to corroborate your answer.  And, I'm pretty sure it's not node 10; Serendipity was not attached to a dead-end like that.

Comment: Double-checked my game, to make sure I'm not going crazy.  Unless DLC modifies the crux, I have *confirmation* that that map is wrong.  Node 10 is correct, but it's connected to node 13, not 12, as shown in the map.

Comment: @fbueckert The map corresponds to my game's crux. The strategy guide mentions the gates in that area are connected in different ways depending on what you did in Episode 3: did you happen to complete Part II before Part I?

Comment: Huh.  I was not aware it was organic like that.  I don't know which I did first; I finished it about two weeks after launch, so it's been collecting dust ever since.

Comment: I will edit my answer to include that information.